# What is the most powerful kind of extratropical cold core cyclone and why?

Tags: meteorology, cyclone

I want to understand what makes for a very strong extratropical cyclone. So which kind on Earth is the strongest in terms of windspeed or pressure? Southern ocean storms, nor'easter, European wind storms etc. And what makes them so strong?

Comment: By what criteria? Max wind speed, pressure in the center?